# How do I use (O365) Exchange Online custom attributes (1 to 15) when I have directory sync enabled and no exchange installed on-premises?

Tags: sync, exchange, active-directory, office365

Here is my setup:

1. Active Directory on premises - with no Exchange installed.
2. DirSync tool to sync all users to Office 365

Now, I need to use [CustomAttributes in Exchange](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee423541%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) - here is where the problems start:

- I can't find the corresponding attributes in my on-premises AD-Schema
- I can't set them directly on Exchange Online because I get an error saying that since the users are synced with on-premises AD, I can't change the custom attributes directly on Exchange Online and must change them in the on-premise AD.

And as I said, I haven't found a way to do this. Can someone help?

Also, I tried to find the attributes directly on the Azure AD to see if I can change them there, but couldn't.

Update: I tried to configure the FIM to not sync those specific attributes thinking that it would somehow unlock them so that I will be able to directly manipulate them on Exchange Online - but no, didn't work. Looks like my only option left is to extend the schema (which I just don't want to do - too afraid it may break something).

Comment: Could you verify if [this article](http://blog.baeke.info/2012/06/24/office-365-identity-management-with-dirsync-without-exchange-server-on-premises/) solves your problem.

Comment: @harrymc - no it doesn't. the stuff described in this article is simple - and already taken care of. it doesn't talk about the custom attributes that exchange uses. as far as I could find those attributes are only created if we add Exchange on-premises - but we don't want to do that and hence asking for help.

Comment: It looks like O365 does not have the required editor, only on-premises does. One workaround I can think of is to make yourself a temporary on-premises Exchange Server. A [Test Drive VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738372.aspx) with Exchange will work only for a predetermined time but may be enough to do the job.

Comment: @harrymc - yes - I am currently going along the lines of extending the schema manually (definitely installing exchange may be better to auto extend the schema, but I am paranoid about making sweeping automated changes to our AD at this time since so many different users are already synced to O365).

What I was wondering is why doesn't the Azure AD that O365 uses not have these attributes already - since it does integrate with Exchange.  That is the question that bugs me - and if it does and I can find a way to edit those, then I will simply add the attributes in the cloud.

Comment: I'm getting a bit out of my depth here, but one idea could be to [connect Windows PowerShell to the Exchange Online service](http://help.outlook.com/en-US/140/cc952755.aspx) and use it to [modify the Exchange Custom Attributes](http://msftedublogger.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/using-and-modifying-exchange-custom-attributes-in-exchange-labs/).

Comment: @harrymc already done that - it basically tells me I can't since I am syncing with on-premises AD and so I have to make change there. I already do everything with Powershell - AD, online AD, and Exchange online. Just can't figure this thing out.

Comment: It is said that because of these admin concerns, Microsoft Support will upon demand supply you with an Exchange serial for an on-premises installation that can be used only for that (DirSync does [sync them](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2256198)), but this will need a heap of calibrations in AD not to louse up your users. A commercial product that pretends to help is [365 Command Active Directory Extensions](http://365command.com/support/active-directory-extensions/), that adds tabs in AD that you can use to set the needed properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing finally (all those months ago) is use the Exchange Setup to only extend the Active Directory Schema. The actual command is setup /ps - this doesn't install exchange but it extends the Active Directory Schema to include the custom attributes (among other exchange attributes).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Office 365 does not have the required editor, only on-premises Exchange does
for the moment.

The official advice is to [connect Windows PowerShell to the Exchange Online service](http://help.outlook.com/en-US/140/cc952755.aspx) and use it to [modify the Exchange Custom Attributes](http://msftedublogger.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/using-and-modifying-exchange-custom-attributes-in-exchange-labs/) by a command such as:

```
Set-Mailbox jonny -CustomAttribute1 'Alumni'
```

As you say that this does not work for you, the solution that is adopted by many people
is to establish an on-premises
Exchange Server specifically for administering the Online schema.
It is said that Microsoft Support will upon demand supply you with a free Exchange serial
for an on-premises installation that can be used only for that purpose.

A commercial product that may help is [365 Command Active Directory Extensions](http://365command.com/support/active-directory-extensions/).
This product adds tabs in AD that you can use to set the needed properties.
The custom attributes you mentioned are included in the [list handled by DirSync](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2256198).

Comment: Thanks - I will give you the bounty anyway. What I ended up doing was to use the exchange setup to only extend the schema.

The command is setup /ps - this only extends the Active Directory Schema to include the exchange attributes.

Comment: You should post your own answer.

Comment: Done as you recommended. Changed that to the accepted answer - hope that didn't take the bounty away.